# object with resistance proportional to velocity differential equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, physics

An object moves through a medium with air resistance proportional to velocity. A $t=0$ the power is cut off so the only force acting on the object is air resistance. At $t=0$ the velocity of the object is $50m/s$ and at 10 seconds the object has slown down to $40m/s$

In the book we are given the formula:

$$\frac{dv}{dt}= \frac{-k}{m} - g$$

where k is a constant and g is the force of gravity $32 ft/s$

write a differential equation for the situation. I can't seem to figure out what the problem is Im not given k and im not given m so how am I supposed to do this? Am I using the wrong formula?

Comment: Shouldn't it be $-kv/m$? The drag force is proportional to velocity.

Comment: The point of the exercise appears to me to be to deduce the value of $k/m$ from the given conditions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem has nothing to do with the formula.

Given that the only force acting the object is air resistance which is proportional to its velocity, you simply have

$$\frac{dv}{dt}=-av$$

Integrate the ode to get,

$$\ln v(t)=-at+C$$

Use the initial condition $v(0) = 50$ to obtain the constant $C$,

$$C=\ln 50$$

Then, use the information at $t=10$, i.e. $v(10) = 40$ to obtain the equation below for resistance constant $a$,

$$\ln 40 = -10a + \ln 50$$

which yields,

$$ a = \frac{\ln 5 - \ln 4}{10}$$

Therefore, the differential equation for the situation is just,

$$\frac{dv}{dt}= \frac{\ln (4/5)}{10}v$$